# NgFor not working when subscribing to a service's subject

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

in a Angular 7 app my ngFor directive is not working and it does not produce any errors either. This is how the app works

1. The component is calling the service during OnInit and at the same time subscribing to the service's subject.
2. During this call the service is fetching some data and when this is done I send a slice of that data to the component.
3. I can see the data in the component but the ngFor does not produce the expected output. It produces nothing basically, as if the data never arrived. Can you please help?

The project is [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/papakonstantinouko/gallery-app).

Comment: By the way, your service logic is complex. You can find better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using "OnPush" and not triggering change detection when you receive your images.

You can either inject the the `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `markForCheck()` on it after assigning your images to `this.images`, but better still you should not handle subscription yourself and "unwrap" your observables :

- change images into an observable
- directly assign the observable returned by the service to that field
- use the AsyncPipe in your template

Answer (score 4):

You have to change your [changeDetection](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) of the component to `Default` by just removing that line  or using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` instead.

OnPush strategy disables automatic change detection.

---

If you have a reason of using `OnPush` strategy in your component, then you have to manually trigger change detection

To do so, you have to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your component:

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

And trigger it after you load the data:

```
getData.subscribe(images => {
  // do something
  this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

before the *ngFor you need to have a div and the div need to have a *ngIf condition after fetch the data from the service then only true the *ngIf Now it shoud work try this.

Comment: The OP is using `OnPush` change detection. Simply adding a div with `*ngIf` has no impact and is not the right solution. Please look at the stackblitz shared.